# angular protractor loop over it('some test') tests

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I have racked my brain and scoured the internet for a way to make a protractor e2e test code synchronous to no avail! What I wish to achieve is to repeat the same protractor test indefinitely until I close the browser or end the tests or to end it via ^(control)c on the command line. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
describe('workspace-project App', () => {
    let page: AppPage;
    let testComplete = false;

    beforeEach(() => {
       page = new AppPage();
    });

    while (true) { // Doesn't work 
        it('should display welcome message', () => {
            page.navigateTo();
            expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to testAngular6!');
            console.log('Executing tests');
            browser.wait(function () { return true; }, 5000);
        });
    }

});
```

but the while loop around the 'it' test does not work and keeps looping around. I realise that I cannot use any of the protractor/ web-driver wait commands or even the rjx interval APIs to achieve this because this is purely a JavaScript problem. Since JavaScript is single threaded. How could I possibly achieve this please? There are a lot of questions on the internet about this but some have no answers and others are at best similar but not quite the same! Thanks very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps this package can help you [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider)

Comment: This is not supported by Jasmine design.  Jasmine will load each spec.js before execute any `it` block inside it.  Jasmine need to know how many `it` block in spec.js after loading. But your `while` loop will generate infinity `it` block.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [interesting article](https://tosbourn.com/using-loops-in-jasmine/)

> What you need to do is wrap your it block inside a function, which you can then call from inside a loop

Example:

> ```
> describe('this is my looping test!', function() {
>   var input = [1,2,3];
>   var output = [10, 20, 30];
>
>   function test_my_times_ten(input, output) {
>     it('should multiply ' + input + ' by 10 to give ' + output, function() {
>       expect(input * 10).toEqual(output)
>     });
>   }
>
>   for(var x = 0; x < input.size; x++) {
>     test_my_times_ten(input[x], output[x]);
>   }
> });
> ```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Oleg. Just wanted to say thank you for your answer. I up voted it and yes it has addressed my woes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi FlexibleMan, thanks for the feedback, but it seems you did not vоte.

Comment: Sorry about that Oleg. I pressed the up vote arrow a few times but it flashes with a pop up briefly to say that votes by people who have a reputation less than 15 are recorded but not shown. Don't know why!!

Comment: You should be able to accept correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers